# Read serial input until control char indicates end of message

Tags: serial-port, arduino, elixir

I'm using [knewter/erlang-serial](https://github.com/knewter/erlang-serial) with Elixir and try to read a JSON-String (e.g. `{"temperature":20.40,"humidity":30.10}` coming in from an Arduino via serial input after it receives a control-signal:

```
defmodule MyApp.SerialInput do
  require Logger


  def start_link do
    serial_pid = :serial.start [{:open, "/dev/cu.usbmodem1431"}, {:speed, 115200}]

    control_signal = "1"
    :timer.send_interval 5000, serial_pid, {:send, control_signal}

    wait_for_new_values serial_pid
  end


  defp wait_for_new_values(serial_pid) do
    receive do
      {:data, jsonString} when is_binary(jsonString) ->
        Logger.debug "received :data #{inspect jsonString}"

    wait_for_new_values serial_pid
  end
end
```

My Problem now is, that I get the serial input split up like that (sometimes it passes through at once):

```
[debug] received :data "{\"t"
[debug] received :data "emperature\":19.00,\"humidity\":42.00}\r\n"

[debug] received :data "{\"temperature\":19.60,\"humidity\":41"
[debug] received :data ".00}\r\n"

[debug] received :data "{\"temperature\":19.50,\"humidity\":40.90}\r\n"

[debug] received :data "{\"temperature\":19.50,\"humi"
[debug] received :data "dity\":40.90}\r\n"

[debug] received :data "{\"temperat"
[debug] received :data "ure\":19.50,\"humidity\":41.30}\r\n"
```

Is there a way to tell the receive block *to wait* until `\r\n` appears at the end of the string or for a fixed amount of characters or something like that? If not, what's the best way to hold state outside of `wait_for_new_values` until `\r\n` appears to then concat these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `receive` block is a pretty low level function, so it will not be able to do such a specialized thing.

State in Elixir is explicit, and can be implemented through an optional argument, the accumulator (`acc` in this case). You can later pass down the accumulated value to the recursive call and only print it when it ends with `"\r\n"`.

```
defp wait_for_new_values(serial_pid, acc \\ "") do
  receive do
    {:data, chunk} when is_binary(chunk) ->
      acc = acc + chunk
  end

  if String.ends_with? acc, "\r\n"
    Logger.debug "received :data #{inspect acc}"
    acc = ""
  end

  wait_for_new_values serial_pid, acc
end
```

Comment: Just a sidenote for OP: using this algorithm, you can get more than one temp-humidity pair. If you want to receive precisely one record, you must scan the buffer for "\r\n" from its beginning.

Comment: Good point, but it seems the control signal triggers a single reading. This may or may not be an issue, depending on the implementation.

Comment: Seems not to be an issue so far, my little Raspberry Pi is running smoothly since yesterday and collected measurements every 30 seconds like a charm.

@MiroslavPrymek The Arduino is only sending a pair of values ofter it receives a control-signal from my Elixir process first (`:timer.send_interval 5000, serial_pid, {:send, control_signal}`) so there shouldn't be more than one pair at a time.